# How to create a bidimensional Gaussian filter on a dense list of points

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, computer-vision, gaussian

I am doing my best to replicate the algorithm described here in this [paper](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/67276/criminisi_tip2004.pdf) for making an inpainting algorithm. The idea is to get the contour or edge points of the part of the image that needs to be inpainted. In order to find the most linear point in the region, the orthogonal normal vector is found. On page 6, a short description of the implementation is given.

> In our implementation the contour
>   **δΩ**  of the target region is modelled as a dense list of image point
>   locations. Given a point **p ∈ δΩ**,  the  normal direction **np**
>   is computed as follows: i) the positions of the
>   “control” points of **δΩ** are filtered via a bi-dimensional Gaussian
>   kernel and, ii) **np** is estimated as the unit vector orthogonal to
>   the line through the preceding and the successive points in the
>   list.

So it appears that I need to put all these points in a gaussian filter. How do I set up a bi-dimensional Gaussian filter when we have a single dimension or a list of points?

Lets say our contour is a box shape at points, then I create a 1 dimensional list of points: [1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3]. Do I need to simply make a new 2d matrix table and put the points in and leave the middle point at [2,2] empty, then run a Gaussian filter on it? This doesn't seem very **dense** though.

I am trying to run this through python libraries.

Answer (score 0):

> a dense list of image points

is simply a line.

You are basically applying a gaussian filter to a black and white image where the line is black and background is white, from what I understand. I think by doing that, they approximate the curve model fitting.

Convolve all of the points in the 2D region surrounding the point and then overwrite the point with the result.

This will make any curve on the edge of the target region less sharp, lowering the noise in the calculation of the normal, which would be the vector orthogonal to the two points that surround the current one.